# How to stop Android Studio documentation panel appearing

Tags: android, ide

I've recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.3.1 and I have noticed the documentation panel now appears whenever I start typing something or do ctrl-space completion. I can't find a way to stop it doing this; I've undocked it, unpinned it, and specified "remove from sidebar" but it just keeps coming back.

What is the point of "remove from sidebar" if it just reinserts itself as soon as I start typing in the editor?

This would be slightly less annoying if it didn't frequently lock up AS while it attempts to get documentation when I'm editing XML files. It's really annoying and driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this trouble, I found the best solution was to grab the left hand edge of the panel and close it right up against the right hand side of the main window, effectively hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Untick this, I occasionally enable it via a keyboard shortcut (I think) and the panel pops open when I hover over a method or class.

In Settings > Editor > Code Editing > Quick Documentation

[image: Android Studio Code Editing Settings]